# Substantial battery life improvement in 18.10. But also video flickers. Are they related?

Tags: power-management, laptop, battery

In Ubuntu 18.04, my battery life was getting so poor that I ordered a new battery from Dell.  I was already doing everything to save battery, running with not-bright screen and the low performance Intel driver (not Nvidia performance video).

After installing 18.10, the battery life is more than doubled. Yesterday I used the system for 4 hours on a wireless network and the battery got down to 13%.  Before the upgrade, it was, at best, 2 hours, often shorter.

I am pretty enthusiastic.

However, I have frequent video flickering that I did not see before. I'm using the XFCE4 desktop and the compiz window manager.  These were OK/stable before, but now, at least once per 30 minutes, I look down and see flickering as the panel is redrawn.  When I plug into a projector, it gets worse. The problem appears like long white "streaks" that jitter.

Articles about power management in Ubuntu say that the designers did not make power-saving changes in the past because of instabilities in access to devices. They mention USB and hard disk, but I wonder if video is related:

https://www.pcmag.com/news/361315/ubuntu-18-10-aims-to-improve-laptop-battery-life